# C#: How to set a string as SqlParameter?

Tags: c#, sql, parameters

I have a DataTable. How to set a certain value of it as one of my SqlParameters?
I receive this error message:
`The SqlParameterCollection only accepts non-null SqlParameter type objects, not String objects.`

Either I do:

```
myCommand.Parameters.Add("@managedBy");
myCommand.Parameters["@managedBy"].Value = comp.Rows[i][4].ToString();

myCommand.Parameters.Add("@modified_at");
myCommand.Parameters["@modified_at"].Value = DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");

myCommand.Parameters.Add("@cn");
myCommand.Parameters["@cn"].Value = comp.Rows[i][1].ToString();
```

or:

```
myCommand.Parameters.Add("@managedBy");
myCommand.Parameters["@managedBy"].Value = (SqlParameter)comp.Rows[i][4];

myCommand.Parameters.Add("@modified_at");
myCommand.Parameters["@modified_at"].Value = DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");

myCommand.Parameters.Add("@cn");
myCommand.Parameters["@cn"].Value = (SqlParameter)comp.Rows[i][1];
```

What am I missing? How to set the parameter from a DataTable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`SqlParameterCollection.Add`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameterCollection.Add%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method overloads with one argument requires that the argument be a `SqlParameter`.  To create an argument with a string name you also need to specify the type (and optionally a size):

```
myCommand.Parameters.Add("@managedBy", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
```

To set the value in one call you can use [`AddWithValue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparametercollection.addwithvalue%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), wihch will infer the SQL type from the value type:

```
myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@managedBy", comp.Rows[i][4]);
```

Answer (score 1):

The SqlParametersCollection inside the SqlCommand object has an Add method that wants an SqlParameter object.

So your code should be something like this

```
 myCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlCommand("@managedBy", SqlDbType.AnsiString)).Value = .......;
```

There are numerous possibilities to add a new parameter to the collection, the easiest of which is

```
 myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@managedBy", comp.Rows[i][4].ToString());
```

This particular version however requires particular care as explained in this [very detailed article on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee236412.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code:

```
myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("ParameterName", anyObject);
```